# IE 7 CSS Layout Issue

Tags: css, layout

In IE 7 I am having an issue on my form. When I test the page for validation errors. I click on the page but don't input anything which produces my validation summary. Then I just put in a username and when I do this the radio button labels for my Account types shift down. But when I mouse over them move back into place. This only happens in IE 7. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening. My code is below:

```
input.account,
label.account,
ul input,
ul label
{
 display: inline;
 /*padding-top: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;*/
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 vertical-align: top;  /*ie likes this */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't your input and label tags be within li tags?  The CSS that you've shown doesn't really tell the whole story.. we'd need to see the whole thing to really get in there and figure out what the issue is.